# regex to replace whole word with specific format C#

Tags: c#, regex

I' m having trouble finding from a string to replace with the format known before. Like this:

- Input : `"#ITEMJIB_{thisIsNumber}, and test but"`
- Output : `"<div class='module_{thisIsNumber}'></div>, and test but".`

thanks for any help

Comment: _"I'm having trouble"_ -- what kind of trouble _specifically_? What did you try? What did that do? How was that different from what you wanted? What _specifically_ do you need help with? Some people's approach notwithstanding, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can match `#ITEMJIB_(\{\d+\})` and replace with `<div class='module_$1'></div>` - the number will be captures to group 1 and used while replacing.

If the curly braces are not a part of your string (`#ITEMJIB_1`), remove `\{` and `\}` from the pattern.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/MxKZn5/1

C# example:

```
var input = "item #ITEMJIB_{1}, and test but #ITEMJIB_{2}";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"#ITEMJIB_(\{\d+\})", "<div class='module_$1'></div>");
```